# drag and drop from listsbox to panel

Tags: c#, winforms, drag-and-drop

I am doing my first drag&drop application. I have a toolbox where you can find labels,button and other components exactly like Visual Studio. And I have panel in the middle. I want the user to drag and drop a button to the panel. I have written some code but doesnt do the drag and drop trick.

here is the screenshot[image]

here is my code which is supposed to handle the drag&drop

```
private void listBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        ListBox box = (ListBox)sender;
        String selectedValue = box.Text;
        DoDragDrop(selectedValue.ToString(), DragDropEffects.Copy);
    }

    private void pnl_form_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Text))
        {
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
        }
        else
        {
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;
        }
    }

    private void pnl_form_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        Label newLabel = new Label();
        newLabel.Name = "testLabel";
        newLabel.Text = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Text).ToString();

        newLabel.AutoSize = true;

        newLabel.Parent = pnl_form;
    }
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember to set `AllowDrop = true` on the control you want to drop something on.

```
private void listBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{        
    String selectedValue = (listBox1.SelectedItem ?? "NULL").ToString();
    DoDragDrop(selectedValue, DragDropEffects.Copy);
}
```

Comment: selectedValue gets the proper name of the selected object. lets say you select a radio button, selectedValue gets set to "Radiobutton"

Comment: @ayilmaz what do you want to drag from the listBox? your code just gets the `Text` of your `ListBox` which is empty.

Comment: it is not empty. For now, I just want to select the button object from the toolbox, get its name which is "Button". then create a label and sets its text to "Button" and drop it into the panel. I am trying the simplest thing for now. but selectedValue is getting the name perfectly

Comment: @ayilmaz if so my code should work. BTW you manually set your `Text` of your `ListBox`? Otherwise, it should be empty as by default.

Comment: thanks for the effort but your code is no different than mine. I tested your code and it didnt do any difference

Comment: @ayilmaz did you try setting `pnl_form.AllowDrop = true`?

Comment: thank you very much. I didnt do the allowdrop=true; thanks for the effort